# MKMapView - Is there a way to use MKUserTrackingModeFollow with a modified center/focus?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a MapView that takes up the full screen and a few elements toward the top of the screen that overlay the map. These top elements potentially cover the blue location marker.

The map is currently tracking fine with MKUserTrackingModeFollow, but I'd like to move the tracking focus down about an inch (obviously the metric will vary by zoom level) to ensure the marker isn't covered. Is there a way to do this with MKUserTrackingModeFollow?

I've considered moving the map with the top elements, but due to design constraints this isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `userTrackingMode` of the MKMapView object to follow the user's location, you could set up a delegate of `CLLocationManager` to receive location tracking events, and with each location update event you receive, set the center coordinate of the map view, with your vertical offset added to the coordinate value.

You can use the various [Map Kit functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html) and MKMapView methods to convert your offset from some fraction of the map view's `bounds.height` to a MKMapPoint or CLLocationDistance value.